# Internet explorer with tinymce creates box when clicked

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, tinymce

I would like to make tinymce work in my CMS with IE but i stumbled over the following problem:

When i click into the editor i get a very ugly box which makes users unhappy.
It is not possible to select more than one paragraph.
I am sure there is a workaround or init setting for this.

[image: Here is an image showing the problem]

**Can anyone help me?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason for this problem. It was a css setting:

```
p {
  min-height : 18px;
}
```

After removal everything worked fine.

Edit: The following css setting had the same unwanted effect:

```
p {
  width : 250px;
}
```

Helpfull link concerning the problem: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html